# Clicking Next Page Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried a number of ways, from xpath to link text to get Selenium to locate the "Next Page" button, and then click until the last page, but just couldn't get this to work.

This is the error that I have using xpath:

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class="next"]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)

Code:

```
import requests, bs4, time, selenium  #import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://egov2.manchesternh.gov/Click2GovTX/accountsearch.html')

select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('searchMethod'))
select.select_by_value('2')

streetName=driver.find_element_by_id('addressName')
time.sleep(1)
streetName.clear()
streetName.send_keys("A")
streetName.send_keys(u'\ue007')

url=driver.current_url
print(url)
driver.get(url)
nxt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a')
nxt.click() 
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the next picture, there are two elements in the page that are identical to the `xpath` syntax you defined.

[image]

In order to get to the second value, you need to define the `xpath` from the parent `div` and `nav`

```
import requests, bs4, time, selenium  #import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://egov2.manchesternh.gov/Click2GovTX/accountsearch.html')

select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('searchMethod'))
select.select_by_value('2')

streetName=driver.find_element_by_id('addressName')
time.sleep(1)
streetName.clear()
streetName.send_keys("A")
streetName.send_keys(u'\ue007')

nxt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="panel-body"]/nav[2]//li[@class="next"]/a')
nxt.click() 
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How did you find out that there are two elements in the page that are identical the xpath that I defined? Did you check for duplications as the first step? Just wanted to see how I can avoid the same problem going forward.

Comment: and you verify your `xpath` by this way. https://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/  please read `From Console panel` section

Answer (score 0):

To get [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to locate the <kbd>Next Page »</kbd> and then click until the last page you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
      from selenium import webdriver
      from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
      from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
      from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
      from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
      from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

      options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
      options.add_argument("start-maximized")
      options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
      options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
      driver.get('https://egov2.manchesternh.gov/Click2GovTX/accountsearch.html')
      select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#searchMethod"))))
      select.select_by_value('2')
      streetName = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control[name='addressName']")))
      streetName.send_keys("A")
      streetName.send_keys(u'\ue007')
      while True:
          try:
              WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p//following::nav[2]//ul//li[@class='next']//a"))).click()
              print("Clicked on  Next Page »")
          except TimeoutException:
              print("No more Next Page »")
              break
      driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
      Clicked on  Next Page »
      Clicked on  Next Page »
      Clicked on  Next Page »
      Clicked on  Next Page »
      Clicked on  Next Page »
      .
      .
      .
      No more Next Page »
  ```